# Add a string to an item array

Tags: c#

I have an item array:

```
dtProducts.Rows[i].ItemArray;
```

I'm trying to append a single string value to the beginning of this array and then add the whole array to another DataTable.

I've tried using .ToList() on the item array, and then add the string value but it gave me an error of:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List**

```
var items = dtProducts.Rows[i].ItemArray.ToList();
items = items.Add("myString");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ItemArray` is not a `DataRow[]`. It is the array of the DataRow's fields. What do you actually want? Append to the beginning is rather vague (at least since you're adding it to the end). Do you want to set the first column's value of the DataRow?

Comment: Pardon my misuse of terminology. Say my array has 10 objects, I would like to add an additional object, at index 0 and keep the rest of the objects as is. In my OP I'm adding it to the end, as that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jason said, List<>.Add is a void method, you should remove the assingment:

```
items.Add("myString");
```

If you want the new item to be in the beginning of the list, use Insert:

```
items.Insert(0, "myString");
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, Jason. Appreciate the quick and simple answers. Sometimes someone else is needed to point out the obvious - I did try numerous syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

The C# List.Add() function adds an item in place, it does not have a return value, so replacing:

```
items = items.Add("myString");
```

with simply

```
items.Add("myString");
```

Should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

`ItemArray` is not a `DataRow[]`. It is the array of the DataRow's fields.

I assume that you want to copy all fields of one `DataTable` to another `DataTable` and fill the first column with a `string`.

```
string[] stringToInsert = new[]{"myString"};
foreach(DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = table2.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = stringToInsert.Concat(row1.ItemArray).ToArray();
}
```

( assuming that the second table has table1.Column.Count + 1 columns )

Answer (score 0):

To add an item at index 0 of the list, you will need to create a new list, add your object, then iterate over the original list adding the objects from it as you go e.g.

```
List<object> newList = new List<object>();
newList.add("myString");
foreach (object item in items)
{
    newList.add(item);
}
```

The add method adds objects to the tail of the list (index n + 1).

Comment: Good call on the Insert method - that's even better.